# New "Sign In With Google" ask for consent with Domain wide delegation applications

Tags: google-signin

Our application is a domain wide delegation applications that can only be install by a **Google Super Admin** from **Google Workspace Marketplace**.

We are migrating from [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) to [Sign In With Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web).

In old Google Sign In library, the user doesn’t need to give is consent because the application is already installed in the domain by the super admin, but the new library asks for the consent. Is this the expected behavior or we need to make a configuration to avoid ask for consent that already was given by de super admin?

List of scope already installed in the domain:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

Consent example:

[image]

Comment: I have pinged someone at google to check into this for you.  Hang in there I will let you know if i hear anything back from them.